# Why is the class an attribute of a factor, but not of a matrix?

Tags: r

I am working my way through Hadleys's Advanced R book to get some deeper understanding of my favourite tool. I came across the following and I was quite puzzled about it. As far as I understand a factor is in fact an integer vector with two attributes attached to is; the factor class and the factor levels. This is confirmed by the following:

```
fac <- factor(letters[1:5]) 
typeof(fac)
class(fac)
attributes(fac)
```

A matrix is created from an atomic vector by adding the dimension attribute to it. I also thought a class was added to it, which seems to be confirmed by calling the class function. However it is not part of its attributes, can anyone explain me why this is not the case where it is with a factor?

```
m <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 5, ncol = 2)
typeof(m)
class(m)
attributes(m)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Matrices (and other arrays) are an implicit class recognized by the dim attribute. See help("matrix") and the language definition.

Comment: See, also, the "Details" section in `?class`.